# Help with a (hopefully simple!) inequality

Tags: inequality

I need to show that

$$\left|\frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{y}\right| \leq \frac{|a+b|+y-x}{y}$$   where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}, \ x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}, \ y > x$

I've puzzled over this for a long time now, and made very little ground. I expect it's rather obvious, but I'm missing something...

Note: this is not homework, it's just a simplified version of an inequality found in a proof, and I want to be convinced!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should it be $|y-x|$?

Comment: Take $a =b=0$ and $y=1$, $x = 2$. It doesn't hold does it?

Comment: Or something like $a=100$, $y=20$, $x=1$, $b=20$, then left is 101 and right is only 6.95.

Comment: In that case I must be understanding it wrong. I'll post back when I've worked out how to re-phrase correctly! thanks

Comment: By increasing $x$, you can get a negative RHS, and by increasing $y$ you can make it as close to $1$ as you want. The inequality can't be right.

Comment: Ok, found an issue with my original question, we have that $y > x$. Edited to show. Still aware it doesn't hold though, working on that.